# YouTube controls/logo and loop

Tags: javascript, youtube

I know that i'm asking 2 questions but I'm looking for a simple solution for apparently a simple thing.

I want a video from youtube to loop and to show no controls/title/logo.

This is what i found so far.

For the loop : youtube recommends setting loop=1 and playlist=video_id. It works and it doesn't in the same time. Why, because the video is reloading over and over again, a loading screen appears every time the video is loaded, it takes so much bandwidth.

I found a website endlessvideo.com , it works so smooth but i don't know how they do it.

And for the controls and logo, i want them hidden. If i'm using modestbranding=1 and controls=0, a title appears.
If i'm adding showinf=0, the logo appears on mouseover the video.

Is there a way to override this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add below options to your link

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?
  iv_load_policy=3&
  loop=1&
  playlist=VIDEO_ID&
  controls=0"
```

`iv_load_policy` setting the parameter's value to 1 causes video annotations to be shown by default, whereas setting to 3 causes video annotations to not be shown. The default value is 1.

`loop` setting the parameter's value to 1 will create a loop, default (stop at the end) value is 0.

`controls` this parameter indicates whether the video player controls are displayed. For IFrame embeds that load a Flash player, it also defines when the controls display in the player as well as when the player will load. Set its value to 0 to not display controls in the player. For IFrame embeds, the Flash player loads immediately.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Comment: loop is working only if i add playlist=video_id and then the title shows

Comment: I've spent the whole day searching a solution for this. But this is not it. If you look closely on the link you gave me Note: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL:
http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID

Comment: So what is your final solution?

Comment: i don't know. this parameters are clearly not working. i'm thinking of using a player that uses the video from youtube. can someone guide me to the right direction. im looking for something very simple and light. play/pause with loop, that's it.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I came here to find an answer, not to give one. If you don't know it's ok, thanks for trying.